# Convert cron format to UTC - Javascript

Tags: javascript, cron, momentjs

I'm using react and I have a function that once is called, it saves a cron into a Postgres database (we are using nodejs for the backend). This is the function `saveSchedule(this.state.schedule)` this `this.state.schedule` is a cron, let's say everyday at 6 am `00 06 * * *` in est time. But I want this value to be saved in UTC in the database, because we handle multiple timezones, so it should be saved as `00 11 * * *`,

Another example in est time, `50 23 * * 1,2,3` this is every Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday at 23:50, in UTC should be saved as `50 4 * * 2,3,4`, at 4:50 Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to affect a crontab entry on a *nix server? Are you doing this from a browser? from a nodejs server-side program? from something else? Javascript & cron don't have a natural connection, so it is entirely unclear what you are trying to do. Cron will do what it does with the crontab entry, regardless of how you would like it to be saved, so `00 06` and `00 11` mean different things to `cron`. There is currently one close-vote for "Too Broad" on your question -- I would vote "unclear what you're asking" because I _really_ can't tell what you're goal is.

Comment: Hi Liz, on top of the comment of Stephen, if I would assume a standard crontab file, then your solution will also be invalid as there is daylight saving time involved. Do you know in which timezone your cron is running? You might try adding `0 * * * * date > /tmp/date.out` which will show your TZ.

Comment: From `man 5 crontab`: The  `CRON_TZ`  variable  specifies the time zone specific for the cron table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time zone into the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local
       time zone, where the daemon is running

Comment: @StephenP I updated the question, I hope is more clear, if its not, please let me know :)

Comment: @LizParody Any progress on this question? I'm trying to solve the same thing right now, and some of these comments here made me wonder if I'm on a fool's errand, especially considering there is daylight savings and other oddities that would have to be accounted for in the "translation" of this cron syntax.

Comment: Hi @BenSteward, unfortunately, I couldn't solve this :(

Comment: @LizParody Yeah, it's tough. I am working around this complicated territory by saving a nextTick property as the millisecond value computed using both the time and the timezone (required parameter to ensure it is always accurate). This nextTick property is then used as the source of truth for my application and updated in the DB any time that job runs. Thanks for the response and for posting the good question!

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to do something similar to this. Let me know if this helps.

```
const cron = require('cron-parser');

function convertCronToGMT(cronExpression, inputTimezone){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const targetTimezone = 'UTC';

        const options = {
            tz: inputTimezone
        };

        const parser = new cron.parseExpression(cronExpression, options);

        const nextOccurrenceInLocalTimezone = parser.next();

        const nextOccurrenceInUTC = moment(nextOccurrenceInLocalTimezone.toISOString()).utc();

        // Extract the UTC cron expression
        const utcCronExpression = `${nextOccurrenceInUTC.minutes()} ${nextOccurrenceInUTC.hours()} * * ${nextOccurrenceInUTC.day()}`;

        resolve(utcCronExpression);
    })

}
```